# The Lorenz gauge in electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge

What is the fundamental reason to fix the [Lorenz gauge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_gauge_condition) to $0$?

Comment: The title should be a question.

Answer (score 3):

It is done for the sake of simplifying the four-vector potential equations that contain an ugly term proportional to $\partial_\mu A^{\mu}$.